# Android: организация прелодера

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!

Возникла такая проблема, не получается написать эффективный прелодер данных.

После авторизации пользователя, на сервер последовательно посылаются 5 запросов, их ответы прасятся и пишутся в базу, данных с сервера приходит не много, но это всё занимает, как оказалось, огромное количество времени и приложение раз через раз падает с диалогом "Приложение повисло, подождать или закрыть?". Попытался поискать на гитхабе похожие REST проекты, но ничего не нашел. Подкиньте пожалуйста идею, как лучше сделать?

Comment: на сколько я знаю,  "Приложение повисло, подождать или закрыть?" появляется только в том случае, когда главный поток долго висит. А как известно, в главном потоке работать с сетью нельзя...

Comment: @нет, с сетью работает он в фоне, приложение на [этой][1] архитектуре написано, но там возврат в главный поток идет после выполнения запроса и только тогда посылается следующий запрос, поэтому происходит так, что главный поток долго выполняется...

[1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/144275/

Comment: я бы так сильно не заморачивался, и делал бы обычными асинктасками.    
Да, они существуют только пока существует активити, но в вашей ситуации, как я понял, они и не нужны вне его...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> возврат в главный поток идет после выполнения запроса и только тогда посылается 
> следующий запрос, поэтому происходит так, что главный поток долго выполняется...

Фактически это все равно означает, что вы "держите" главный поток - поэтому все и падает. Надо делать не так:

1. Из фонового сервиса/потока/асинктаска шлем запрос на сервер
2. По получению запроса пишем результаты в локальную БД
3. Над локальной БД рисуем `ContentProvider`
4. Над `ContentProvider` рисуем `CursorLoader` и результаты читаем в основном потоке например через `ListView`

В этом случае отрисовка результатов будет происходить по мере получения ответа от сервера без задержки юайного потока.

**Update** [здесь Google покрасивше расписал](http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-developing-RESTful-android-apps.pdf) как это должно работать.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем Вы используете сервис для этого? Мой вам совет: юзайте [Async Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

Это красивая, удобная обертка вокруг Apache HTTP Client с человеческим лицом, которая содержит callbacks на все случаи жизни, в вашем случае onProgress и которые уже в UI-потоке, при том, что основные операции происходят в фоне(что-то вроде AsyncTask, выражаясь простым языком). Вы пишите запрос - в onProgress(уточните в документации) показываете крутяшку свою с сообщением - получаете ответ в методе onSuccess или если ошибка в onFailure.

Comment: В своих проектах использую Android-query (AQuery) https://code.google.com/p/android-query/. Тоже очень удобен и хорошо документирован.